# Hadith about noises and questions during sermon?

Tags: hadith, source-identification

I remember that there was some verse or hadith that said something about those people who used to make noises and silly questions and used to make fun out of that when the Last Prophet S.A.W.W used to talk about Islam. Please somebody help me find the exact reference!

Answer (score 1):

One is not to play, talk, or distract oneself.  Even if one distracts himself with the smallest of things.  The prophet (peace and blessings be upon Him) said:

> إِذَا قُلْتَ لِصَاحِبِكَ يَوْمَ الْجُمُعَةِ أَنْصِتْ‏.‏ وَالإِمَامُ
> يَخْطُبُ فَقَدْ لَغَوْتَ
>
> When the Imam is delivering the Khutba, and you ask your companion to
> keep quiet and listen, then no doubt you have done an evil act.
>
> [Saheeh Bukari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/11/58)

He (peace and blessings be upon Him) also said:

> من مس الحصا فقد لغا‏
>
> One who distracts himself with pebbles during the Khutbah will not get
> the (Jumu'ah) reward
>
> [Saheeh Muslim/Riyaddussaliheen](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/1/128)